# Merging two Bash arrays into key:value pairs via a Cartesian product

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, shell, cartesian-product

I have two arrays `A` and `B`. How do I combine them into a new array `C`, which is their Cartesian product? For example, given:

```
A=( 0 1 )
B=( 1 2 )
```

Desired output:

```
C=( 0:1 0:2 1:1 1:2 )
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Bash supports sparse arrays, it's better to iterate over the array than to use an index based on the size.

```
a=(0 1); b=(2 3)
i=0
for z in ${a[@]}
do
    for y in ${b[@]}
    do
        c[i++]="$z:$y"
    done
done
declare -p c   # dump the array
```

Outputs:

```
declare -a c='([0]="0:2" [1]="0:3" [2]="1:2" [3]="1:3")'
```

Answer (score 158):

If you don't care about having duplicates, or maintaining indexes, then you can concatenate the two arrays in one line with:

```
NEW=("${OLD1[@]}" "${OLD2[@]}")
```

Full example:

```
Unix=('Debian' 'Red hat' 'Ubuntu' 'Suse' 'Fedora' 'UTS' 'OpenLinux');
Shell=('bash' 'csh' 'jsh' 'rsh' 'ksh' 'rc' 'tcsh');
UnixShell=("${Unix[@]}" "${Shell[@]}")
echo ${UnixShell[@]}
echo ${#UnixShell[@]}
```

Credit: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

Comment: This concatenates the two arrays which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, Yep, but Google will send thousands of people here looking for this answer. I'm glad it's here.

Comment: While it's a useful technique, it should also be noted that the indices of the source arrays are lost. When the destination array is created, new indices are generated.

Comment: Anyone who wants to use this method should test it thoroughly before putting it in their code. When `-n` is in one of the arrays, it is omitted in the merged array. To see this, run the following code: `a=(-m -n -o); b=(-p -q -r); c=("${a[@]}" "${b[@]}"); for i in "${c[@]}"; do echo $i; done`. Also, putting it in quotes doesn't help.

Comment: @Dave F, the missing `-n` is not an issue of the array concatination. That works as expected. It is missing, because `echo` interprets it as an option to not output a newline.

Comment: why does this work?

Comment: This is a fine answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38316001/9636

Comment: I disagree with the notion that we should dilute the quality of SE answers because search engines aren't (yet) discerning enough to allow mindless click through without reading the title. That creates a garbage in, garbage out future.

Answer (score 5):

here's one way

```
a=(0 1)
b=(1 2)
for((i=0;i<${#a[@]};i++));
do
    for ((j=0;j<${#b[@]};j++))
    do
        c+=(${a[i]}:${b[j]});
    done
done

for i in ${c[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: The second `for` loop should use double quotes around the array reference.  This preserves significant spaces in the array values.  Try it with `a=("foo bar" "baz quux")`.  The `c+=` assignment similarly needs to quote the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I merged two arrays in Bash:

Example arrays:

`AR=(1 2 3)
BR=(4 5 6)`

One Liner:

`CR=($(echo ${AR[*]}) $(echo ${BR[*]}))`

Comment: There's no need to use $() and this doesn't preserve spaces in the values (if they exist).
    
   `a=("some words" some single words)`  
  
   `b=(one two three "words with spaces")`  
  
   `n=("${a[@]}" "${b[@]}")`  
  
You can also just append to one of them with `+=`   

   `a+=("${b[@]}")`  
   `

Comment: This only works if every element is space delimited. If you used readarray to feed elements in based on lines this will not work.

Answer (score -2):

One line statement to merge two arrays in bash:

```
combine=( `echo ${array1[@]}` `echo ${array2[@]}` )
```

Comment: That will re-split the elements.  You probably meant `combine=("${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}")`.  Which is then what Ian Dunn said.

Comment: The quoting error is exacerbated by the [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)