# How do I combine two arrays into a third array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have two arrays: `array1` and `array2`:

```
array1=( a b c )
array2=( 1 2 3 )
```

How do I make a third array, `array3`:

```
array3=( a b c 1 2 3 )
```

This question is different from [Combine arrays in the beginning of a for-loop (Bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180583/combine-arrays-in-the-beginning-of-a-for-loop-bash) because this deals exclusively with combining arrays, not whether such a statement is legal within a for loop.

This question is different from [Merging two Bash arrays into key:value pairs via a Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986023/9636) because I'm just trying to concatenate two arrays rather than combine them in a `key:value` style.

Comment: Someone suggested closing my question in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986023/9636 but the suggestion is asking a more complicated question. I suspect this suggestion happened because one of the answers applies to my question, but not the suggested one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579195/9636

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide example 27-10](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html#ARRAYAPPEND), with a correction:

```
declare -a array1=( zero1 one1 two1 )
declare -a array2=( [0]=zero2 [2]=two2 [3]=three2 )
dest=( "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" )
echo "${dest[@]}"
zero1 one1 two1 zero2 two2 three2
```

Thus, for my case, it's:

```
array3=( "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" )
```

Comment: The fact that John1024 had to correct the ABS (by quoting the array expansions here) is why we discourage people from linking to the ABS.

Comment: What is a better resource?

Comment: Either the man page (`man bash`) or the [on-line manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).